# Merge two row into two column with third column same as it is

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have SQL output like this :

```
LINE       SIZE      TOT_COUNT  
A           20           113  
A           40             3  
B           20             4  
B           40             2  
C           20           142  
C           40           452
```

But I want like this:

```
LINE       20             40  
A         113              3  
B           4              2  
C         142            452
```

Note: This is already a output, not any column of any table.

Comment: Dont ask the [same question again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838008/merge-two-row-into-two-column-with-third-column-same-as-it-is)

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar - you voted to close that other question - perhaps in response to the poor formatting instead of the actual content.  As it's closed nobody can post an answer until people vote to reopen it.  Under the circumstances the OP's approach is understandable.  Voting to close this question as a duplicate of a closed question *which has no answers* is pointless and punitive.

Comment: I agree @APC. OP Has to make that question sensible. This question is simply a copy and paste again. So, all those close votes for that questions now go pointless!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar - but the question *is understandable*.  It's just another instance of that old chestnut, row-to-column transposition.  Votes to close as duplicate should point to a  question which has an answer, preferably accepted.

Comment: Yes, this question is definitely understandable. But not a question but order. Okay lets end our conversation here. No offense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    line,
    sum(case size when 20 then tot_count end) as "20",  -- use min is the same.
    sum(case size when 40 then tot_count end) as "40"
from 
    your_table
group by
    line
```

If the first output is from another query, you can replace `your_table` with your query as an sub query.

Comment: This will work if your values are static (20,40). There is a better approach which would be a crosstab which is dynamic but i dont have my premade script here.

Comment: @TheProvost - A dynamic approach is not better if the requirement is for a fixed number of columns.

Comment: @APC yes thats why i said "IF"...this is of course a very valid answer to the question which i already upvoted...i was just trowing in in there in case someone comes here searching for a way to replicate this with dynamic columns which is more common :)